# Calculating tape length to store an amount of records

Tags: operating-system

Consider a magnetic tape drive with density=1666 bpi and IBG=0.5 inch. How many inches of tape are required to store 50,000 records, each record is 120 bytes. Blocking factor  is 45.

I don't understand how to convert the units to an answer...

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify how many bits per byte, but if you assume 8 bits is 1 byte, then each 120 byte record will be 120 * 8 = 960 bits.

The total number of bits in 50,000 records will be 50,000 * 960 = 48000000 bits. At a density of 1666 bpi, this is 48000000 / 1666 = 28811.5 inches.

Then, as your blocking factor (I'm assuming this means the number of records per data block), is 45, and you have 50,000 records, you will need 50,000 / 45 = 1112 blocks (rounded up), so there will be 1111 inter-block gaps (IBG). Therefore, you will have 1111 * 0.5 inches of IBG = 555.5 inches.

In total, you will have 28811.5 + 555.5 = 29367 inches of tape.

You'll need to double-check my assumption of the terminology and also the underlying size of a single byte in bits.